# Dark Theme with extended properties

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt5

### Goal

While building a pyqt5 based gui that includes `QListWidget` with many dynamicly generated `QListWidgetItem`. Some of the `QListWidgetItem` have colors indicator based on properties of what they open when clicked.

So far i only used the default color theme and used a brush with .setBackground to each of the list items at creation to get the color scheme i had in mind.

Right now i attempt at adding a new dark theme while also changing colors dynamicly after the creation of the objects. To do that i created a new palette and set the palette for the app.

### expected and actual results

To handle the list items i first attempted at setting a property as follows:

```py
item.setProperty('cool', True)
```

This returned an error indicating `QListWidgetItem` has no `setProperty` attribute which i think the reasen for is that `QListWidgetItem` does not inherit `QObject`

Then i attempted at creating my own class to set the property:

```py
class ThemedQListWidgetItem(QListWidgetItem):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QListWidgetItem.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.cool = False
```

and setting the colors using:

```py
app.setPalette(darkPalette)
app.setStyleSheet("""
            ThemedQListWidgetItem[cool="true"] {
                background-color: red;}
            ThemedQListWidgetItem[cool="false"] {
                background-color: palette(base);}
        """)
```

The dark theme is applied but no red colored items are shown, and I don't get any errors.

Maybe im doing something wrong regarding the way pyqt is ment to be used. There must be a simple way to dynamicly change colors based on properties of gui elements.

While i could rebuild the whole list from scratch every time i doubt there isn't a better way.

### My enviorment

- Archlinux x64 kernel 5.10.5
- Desktop Enviorment: Xfce4
- Window Maneger:     Xfwm4
- Python Version:     3.9.1
- Pyqt5 Version:      5.15.2

Comment: Q*WidgetItems are *not* actual GUI elements, but abstract representations of the items that the item view uses. Qt stylesheets can only be applied to *actual* widgets (objects that inherit from QObject and QWidget), so the property selector that you're trying to use will not work because a QListWidgetItem is *not* a QWidget, and stylesheets only access Qt properties, so you cannot use a simple python attribute. If you want individual colors for each item, you either use the `setBackground()` (which is the same as using `setData()` with BackgroundRole, or you create a custom delegate.

Comment: in that case would an example for delegation be to extend the `QListWidget` class with the colors for each item type as attributes and let it update the item's color using `setBackground`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The QListWidgetItem are a representation of the information shown by the QListWidget, so the Qt StyleSheet cannot be used for painting as they are not visual elements. QListWidget uses the QSS to paint the visual items (in addition to using the information from the QListWidgetItem). So if you want a property based painting then you could do it through a delegate:

```py
import random
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QListWidget,
    QListWidgetItem,
    QStyledItemDelegate,
)

CoolRole = Qt.UserRole


class Delegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def initStyleOption(self, option, index):
        super().initStyleOption(option, index)
        if index.data(CoolRole):
            option.backgroundBrush = QColor("red")


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QListWidget()
    delegate = Delegate(w)
    w.setItemDelegate(delegate)
    for i in range(10):
        it = QListWidgetItem()
        it.setText(f"item {i}")
        cool = random.choice((True, False))
        it.setData(CoolRole, cool)
        w.addItem(it)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: This works great, i had some issue at start becouse i didnt realize `Qt.UserRole` is an integer, rather then an object. and i tried to use 2 roles with the same id.
Thank you very much for your help.